# List altered without order to do so

Tags: c

I don't even know how to title this question, but it's following: in my code I'm duplicating a Queue (which in this case is nearly the same as a linked list ) and changing the duplicate, but the original is getting changed aswell. I don't see where I'm changing it so, i hope someone can help. the printf are to ilutrate my point, they should have the same output all the way.

```
int list(Queue list, int sort )
{
    Queue temp = list ;

    int s=temp->size ;
    int i=0, j, p;
    int *sender, *receiver ;
    char **sorted ;
    char* t ;

    if ( list == NULL )
    {
        puts("NULL") ;
        return 0;
    }


    t=(list->head->item->text);
    printf("%s", t );

    sorted = malloc((s + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    sender = malloc( s * sizeof(int));
    receiver = malloc( s * sizeof(int));

    while ( i < s )
    {
        /* It's changing somewhere around here */

        sorted[i] = malloc(strlen(temp->head->item->text) + 1);
        strncpy( sorted[i] , temp->head->item->text, strlen(temp->head->item->text) + 1 ) ;
        sender[i] = temp->head->item->sender ;
        receiver[i] = temp->head->item->receiver ;
        if (temp->head->next == NULL)
        break;
        temp->head = temp->head->next ;
        i++ ;
    }

    t=(list->head->item->text);
    printf("%s", t );
```

Comment: `strncpy` could be replaced with `strcpy`, it would make the code clearer.

Comment: On early testing I had an erros with strcpy so I used strncpy, but now I replaced it and it worked. So thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Queue temp = list ;` **does not** duplicate your queue. It duplicates the `Queue` struct, but that struct does not hold the queue. Rather - it holds pointers to the `head` of the queue(and since it's a queue - probably to it's `tail` too). When you copy the struct the `head` pointer remains the same, which means that you are modifying the same nodes.

If you want to duplicate the queue, you have to iterate over all elements and copy each one of them to the new queue.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumption

`Queue` is actually a typedef for something like `struct RealQueue *`. That is, it is a pointer.

### Where you've gone wrong...

We perform:

```
Queue temp = list;
```

At this point, `temp == list` because they are both pointers that point to the same object.

We then modify `temp`:

```
temp->head = temp->head->next;
```

However, this **also** modifies `list`. Both `temp` and `list` are pointers that **point to the same object**.

### Therefore...

At the end of your while loop, both `list->head` and `temp->head` point to the last object in the queue.

### To fix this...

You probably want to store variables to whatever type `list->head` is.

Comment: This is sort of what I ended up doing. I stored the list->head in a variable at the beggining and restored it in the end. Solved it. Thanks!